# Implementing Polynomial Regression in Python (error:could not convert)

Tags: python, memory, regression, polynomials

## Hello world,

## Problem

Currently, trying to predict the margin (in percent) from a dataframe with 48098 rows and 70 features (all types). After that, the get dummies has been done in order to have only numerical values, which give the following shape (Shape Df is: (48098, 572)).

However, since the exploration step, we could have seen that the target doesn't really follow a normal distribution (as shown on images). 
[image]

[image]

Therefore, the performance are 0.76 and 0.74 on respectively the training and the test set.

## Things tried

Some solutions have been tried such as:

- Fitting the whole X set (before the train/test) split which give the following error:

### First Error:

Thus, the polynomial regression has been tried to implement. The problem comes when the function (PolynomialFeatures) fit the training set. In fact, the following error appears:

```
  MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-19-bf8dbdba1272> in <module>
  3 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
  4 poly = poly.fit(X_train)
 ----> 5 X_poly = poly.transform(X_train)

  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in transform(self, X)
     1504             XP = sparse.hstack(columns, dtype=X.dtype).tocsc()
     1505         else:
 -> 1506             XP = np.empty((n_samples, self.n_output_features_ dtype=X.dtype)
    1507             for i, comb in enumerate(combinations):
    1508                 XP[:, i] = X[:, comb].prod(1)

MemoryError:
```

- Fitting Polynomial Features before get dummies, in order to have less columns than 500, which give the following ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Loans'.

#### Second Errors:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e379555bc257> in <module>
  5 # the default "include_bias=True" adds a feature that's constantly 1
  6 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
----> 7 poly = poly.fit(X)
  8 X_poly = poly.transform(X)


   1458         self : instance
   1459         """
-> 1460         n_samples, n_features = check_array(X, accept_sparse=True).shape
   1461         combinations = self._combinations(n_features, self.degree,
   1462                                           self.interaction_only,


    565         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    566         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 567             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    568         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    569             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

 ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Loans'
```

## Some Code

First: Polynomial

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
 y  = df.MARGIN
 X = df.drop('MARGIN', axis=1)
 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
 poly = poly.fit(X)
 X_poly = poly.transform(X)
```

Second: Train/Test split

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    y = df_ohe.MARGIN
    X = df_ohe.drop('MARGIN', axis=1)
    # Split into Tain and Test set
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
```

## Expected Solution

The expected results would be to complete the polynomial regression and having some thing like:

#### First: Implementing polynomial Regression on X

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=10, include_bias=False)
 poly.fit(X)
 X_poly = poly.transform(X)
```

#### Second: Split X on training and test set

X_train and X_test would be with the polynomial features ?

#### Third: Predicting

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
lr_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
train_R2_lr = lr.score(X_train, y_train)
test_R2_lr = lr.score(X_train, y_test)
print("Training set score: {:.2f}".format(train_R2_lr))
print("Test set score: {:.2f}".format(test_R2_lr))
```

### Questions:

- When do we implement get_dummies? (after, before the split)
- How to do when we have that many columns?
- Is it the 'good' way to do so? (New on this field so any help is the welcome)

If you have any suggestion, do not hesitate to share and Thanks in advance for those who would take time.

Have a good day/night!